# Data Frame index name axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I was wondering if anyone could please tell me how to set the "index name" in the same axis as the column names in a data frame.
In the image below, I am trying to put the word "count" on the same line as the column headers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's already named. If you do `df2.reset_index()` it will be at the same level as the column headers (it will become a column)

Comment: You are looking for df2.columns.name='count'

Comment: `df2.rename_axis('count', axis=1)` or `df2,columns.name = "count"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this doc: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html

```
df2.index.name = None
df2.rename_axis("count", axis="columns", inplace=True)
```

As [Wen said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446784/data-frame-index-name-axis/52449161#comment91836467_52446784), it's same with adding a name to the "column header".

```
df2.columns.name = "count"
```